# Are there any Taizé worship services in Helsinki?

Tags: religion, finland, helsinki

I'm going to Helsinki for 4 days. Where I live, I go to a Taizé worship service.

Are there any Taizé services in Helsinki? If so, how could I make contact and join the prayer service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Finnish Evangelical Lutheran Church arranges weekly prayers and monthly masses that include Taizé-songs in the Mustasaari chapel from June 8th to August 10th on Thursdays at 6:30pm. Mustasaari is an island on the West coast of Helsinki, you need to take a ferry there. You don't have to contact them, just arrive there when there's a prayer or a mass.

> [Ecumenical Prayer of Trust](http://www.luottamuksenmessu.fi/) is a beautiful service with Taizé-songs,
>   Bible texts and meditative silence. The songs are sung in different
>   languages and the texts and parts of the intercerssions are read in
>   English. After the prayer we drink tea together. Once a month there is
>   a Mass of Trust. The mass is held by the Finnish Evangelical Lutheran
>   Church and is open for everyone.

Also the [Käpylä Church](http://www.helsinginkirkot.fi/en/churches/kapyla-church) arranges Taizé-inspired prayers every Wednesday at 6pm.